# Splitting NoName column in SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc, ado

I want to use a CSV file **Test1.csv** to create a Recordset with customized column names.

The CSV file format:

```
    (Blank)  |  SomeAggr |   (Blank) |   Div1  |  Div2  |  Div3
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    G0.1     |  1.23     |           |   ABC   |  DEF   |  GHI
    G0.2     |  2.45     |           |   JKL   |  MNO   |  PQR
    G0.3     |  9.02     |           |   STU   |  VWX   |  YZA
    G1.1     |  3.32     |           |   ZYX   |  WVU   |  TSR
    G1.2     |  5.53     |           |   QPO   |  NML   |  KJI
    G1.3     |  1.15     |           |   HGF   |  EDC   |  BAZ
    G1.4     |  4.65     |           |   FKJ   |  OTU   |  WKL
```

The 1st & 3rd Columns have blank headers. The 1st column contains data I want to split it into two columns as shown in SQL Query.

Note - I am creating a recordset and do not want to do any transformations using a WorkSheet.

The final Recordset via SQL Query should look like this:

```
    GVal  |   Pos    |  Aggr     |   (Blank) |   DV A  |  DV B  |  DV C
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    0     |    1     |  1.23     |           |   ABC   |  DEF   |  GHI
    0     |    2     |  2.45     |           |   JKL   |  MNO   |  PQR
    0     |    3     |  9.02     |           |   STU   |  VWX   |  YZA
    1     |    1     |  3.32     |           |   ZYX   |  WVU   |  TSR
    1     |    2     |  5.53     |           |   QPO   |  NML   |  KJI
    1     |    3     |  1.15     |           |   HGF   |  EDC   |  BAZ
    1     |    4     |  4.65     |           |   FKJ   |  OTU   |  WKL
```

I am running the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim strDataSource$, strF1$, strFF1$, strSql$, oCon as Object, oRs as Object, i%, Fld
    strFF1 = "Test1.csv"
    strF1 = "`C:\Users\adam\Downloads\Test Folder`\"
    strDataSource = Thisworkbook.Path

    Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & strDataSource & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=Yes;"

   'Getting Top 1 row to loop through fields and create SQL string accordingly.
    strSql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " & strF1 & strFF1
    oCon.Open strCon
    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSql)

    i = 1
    strSql = "SELECT "    
    For Each Fld In oRs.Fields

        Select Case True
            Case Is = Fld.Name = "NoName"    '1st NoName column
                If Fld.Value <> vbNullString Then
                    strSql = strSql & "CLng(Replace(Left(" & Fld.Name & ", InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", ""."") - 1), ""G"", """"))" & " AS [GVal], "
                    strSql = strSql & "CLng(Right(" & Fld.Name & ", Len(" & Fld.Name & ") - InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", ""."")))" & " AS [Pos], "
                Else
                    strSql = strSql & Fld.Name & ", "  '2nd NoName column
                End If
            Case Is = Fld.Name = "SomeAggr"
                strSql = strSql & "[" & Fld.Name & "] AS [Aggr],"
            Case Is = InStr(1, Fld.Name, "Div") > 0
                strSql = strSql & "[" & Fld.Name & "] AS [DV " & Chr(i + 64) & "], "
                i = i + 1
        End Select
    Next Fld

    If Right(Trim(strSql), 1) = "," Then strSql = Left(Trim(strSql), Len(Trim(strSql)) - 1)
    strSql = strSql & " FROM " & strF1 & strFF1

    oRs.Close

' >>> getting error on below `Set oRs` line
  [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] '' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

    Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSql)
Stop

ExitSub:
    oRs.Close
    oCon.Close
    Set oRs = Nothing
    Set oCon = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error No: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "An Error occurred!"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume ExitSub

End Sub
```

Here is the SQL Query.

```sql
SELECT CLng(Replace(Left(NoName, InStr(NoName,".")-1), "G", "")) AS [GVal], 
CLng(Right(NoName, Len(NoName) - InStr(NoName,"."))) AS [Pos], 
[SomeAggr] AS [Aggr],
[Div1] AS [DV A], 
[Div2] AS [DV B], 
[Div3] AS [DV C] 
FROM `\C:\Users\Adam\Downloads\Test Folder`\Test1.csv
```

The code gives me the following error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] '' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

I don't know how to get a reference or select the 1st Blank Column to split it's values into two columns.

The Query works in MSAccess and the **1st NoName column** is shown as **Field1** and **2nd NoName column** is shown as **Field3**.

Comment: It might be useful to post the completed SQL statement that you are producing. I'm guessing that simply specifying a column alias will fix this (`SELECT xyz AS ColumnAlias`).

Comment: @Martin as you can see i am specifying aliases e.g. splitting `1st column as [GVal],` and `1st column as [Pos]`. Not Working!!! Let me see if i can edit the post to share the SQL Query.

Comment: Have you tried doing `Debug.Print strSql` right before the problem line, so you can verify the string value is as expected?

Comment: @Mistella, did you just delete your earlier comment? That was the `ANSWER`! It is working now. :-) Can you post your answer again, so that i can accept it as the Solution? Thanks a bunch! ....(Learning from my mistakes)

Comment: @sifar I'll repost my comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL code expects single quotes as string deliminators instead of double quotes. In the `For Each Fld In oRs.Fields` loop, there are two lines which use double quotes instead of single quotes while constructing `strSql`:

```
strSql = strSql & "CLng(Replace(Left(" & Fld.Name & ", InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", ""."") - 1), ""G"", """"))" & " AS [GVal], "
strSql = strSql & "CLng(Right(" & Fld.Name & ", Len(" & Fld.Name & ") - InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", ""."")))" & " AS [Pos], "
```

These should be changed to:

```
strSql = strSql & "CLng(Replace(Left(" & Fld.Name & ", InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", '.') - 1), 'G', ''))" & " AS [GVal], "
strSql = strSql & "CLng(Right(" & Fld.Name & ", Len(" & Fld.Name & ") - InStr(" & Fld.Name & ", '.')))" & " AS [Pos], "
```

Comment: Thanks @Mistella for pointing out what i was doing wrong...learning from my mistakes... :-)

Answer (score 0):

when i try to replicate your code i get the following:
a) Not sure if it is the problem but you have two columns names [NoName] so you need to distinguish between the two. (b) Could you to put the NoName columns in square brackets and try single quotes instead of double quotes?

```
SELECT 
    CLng(Replace(Left(NoName, InStr(NoName, ".") - 1), "G", "")) AS [GVal],
    CLng(Right(NoName, Len(NoName) - InStr(NoName, "."))) AS [Pos], [SomeAggr] AS [Aggr],
    NoName, 
    [Div1] AS [DV A], 
    [Div2] AS [DV B], 
    [Div3] AS [DV C] 
FROM 
    `C:\Temp`\Test.csv
```

Comment: the Recordset already gives the `NoName` name to columns with no Header. As for the Solution, which was given by Mistella, it is to use single-quotes, instead of double-quotes, for the '.' , 'G' , and '' . Hope this helps.